# Paraview: open pcd file

Tags: paraview

I would like to know if paraview can manage pcd file and how. I saw here https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/PCL_Plugin that paraview has a pluggin in order to be able to use some functionalities of pcl but I did not see anything related to manage pcd file. And when I tried to open the pcd file with paraview the file format is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the PCL plugin is outdated and not integrated into the release of ParaView. Is should be upgraded and added into the paraview default plugin. MRs are welcome on our [gitlab](http://www.gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview).

In the meantime, you can either:

- convert your `.pcd` file in [CloudCompare](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/) to `.vtk`
- use [pcd2ply](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/tools) to convert it to `.ply`

before loading it in ParaView.

Edit : Some PointCloud tools can sometimes generate a dataset without any cells, wich is not supported by ParaView and your point cloud will be invisible.

If fixing the file generation is not possible, then the easiest way is to add a cell manually in ParaView.

- Open Your .ply file, check that there is no Cells in the information tab
- Add a Python Programmable Filter
- Set the script to the following

Script:

```
pdi = self.GetPolyDataInput()
pdo =  self.GetPolyDataOutput()
pdo.ShallowCopy(pdi)
numPts = pdo.GetNumberOfPoints()
ids=vtk.vtkIdList()
ids.SetNumberOfIds(numPts)
for i in range(0, numPts):
  ids.SetId(i, i)
pdo.Allocate(1)
pdo.InsertNextCell(2, ids)
```

- And Apply, your point cloud should appear

Comment: Hi Mathieu, I have an issue with the .ply. Now I am saving my data with plc in .ply format but paraview is not displaying anything. My points are XYZRGB (standard pcl type). I reviewed the file and the data seems to be fine. In order to store the data I am using savePLYFileASCII from pcl. It is curious because when I check the information of the file in paraview. It is displaying that I have 307200 points(it is correct) and that I have a rgb unsigned char vector (that it is correct).

Comment: How many cells does your dataset have ? 0 ? 1 ? 307200 ? 
You can try adding a Glyph Filter with a sphere source to visualize your points.

Comment: Number of cells 0. Number of points 307200. This is my file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lhpBut9uvhkD9NeCO7n7cO3-RhimdFYw. I tried with the glyph filter and yes is showing something but I want to have only points and with the glyph filter I do not know how to show only points, far as I see I only can put some geometric forms like, arrows, spheres, and so on

Comment: Your dataset does not have any cells defined. This is not supported by ParaView. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! The only thing that it is missing at this moment is the rgb value. how can I add the rgb value to the points?

Comment: Thanks Mathieu. It is working. In order to learn to extend your script. Can you please recommend me any reference? For instance, I have one case that I have stored on ply format that contains XYZ VX VY VZ and I would like to use vx, vy and vz in order to display arrows.

Comment: Reference for programmable filter : https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_Programmable_Filter, but this is usually not easy to use. What you are trying to achieve would be much simpler to do by then adding a Calculator and creating a vector with it, before displaying them with a glyph filter.

Comment: Yep, This is that I tried first but without success. The thing is at this moment Paraview is not recognizing dx dy dz and it is only loading x, y ,z. My file has the same format of the rgb file(it is a ply without cells) but instead of having rgb values has vx,vy,vz.  And I want to take these vx,vy,vz and with the calculator create the vector but at this moment I can not take it this values.

Comment: I would suggest taking this discussion to the mailing list of ParaView : https://www.paraview.org/mailing-lists/

Comment: Of course,  during today I will subscribe to the email list and also I will write an email with a brief of all of this topic in order to continue the discussion. Thanks!